# Could not resolve 'A' from state '' in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've getting deranged about this problem, this is my app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','config'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'main',
    templateUrl: 'index.html'
  });
  $stateProvider.state('products', {
    url: '/products',
    templateUrl: 'products.html'
  });


});
```

this is my controller

```
.controller('main', function ( $scope, $ionicModal, $state, $http) {
```

And using
    $state.go('products');

or

```
$state.go('products', {});
```

or

```
ui-sref="products"
```

all of them prompt this error:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'main' from state ''
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3074)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3007)
    at Scope.$scope.adds (main-controller.js:12)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:27615), <anonymous>:4:203)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65290
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30372)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30472)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65289)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16764)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16752)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:26771(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:23484Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:30477(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:65289defaultHandlerWrapper @ ionic.bundle.js:16764eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:16752triggerMouseEvent @ ionic.bundle.js:2953tapClick @ ionic.bundle.js:2942tapTouchEnd @ ionic.bundle.js:3069
```

However, all of my states are always prompted as "undefined" when calling state.this or generally moving from side to side, basically I've tried everything I've found on this side, but NOTHING works. Absolutely nothing, for some obscure reason it just doesn't load the main state as 'main' nor loads to main or products or any state, the pages are seen IF accessed via the weburl.

Error on imports and names, had to change the controller to starter.ctrl and put on starter ['ionic', 'ui.router', 'stater.ctrl'] then it worked.

Comment: I don't see where you have injected a dependency on `ui.router`, but it must be somewhere. Is there some other place where you are registering your base app?

Comment: Yes, on index.html, still doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Any errors in the console? BTW, I was referring to an `angular.module()` definition for your main app. Also, I've not seen this before: `angular.module('starter', ['ionic','config', 'starter'])` where you are apparently injecting a dependency **on** `starter` in the definition **for** `starter`.

Comment: Oh! Yes that was my mistake was trying things and looked on an old project where I had the controller declared as Stuff.Controller and attempted to use that, nevermind that. On console I only get the $status error when I try to go anywhere, plus the $status.this gives undefined. Tried adding ui.router on module( 'starter', ['ionic', 'config', 'ui.router']) but still doesn't work, now instead gives Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'config' is not available!

Comment: I'm confused. You're using ui-router, right? There is no `$state.this` (I'm guessing `$status.this` was a typo in your previous comment). Can you update your question to show the **exact** code you are using and the **exact** error(s) you are seeing in the console?

Comment: Oh, didn't know looked online and someone said that to check which state you're in you had to do $state.this (still gives '' on current state when trying to move, when it should say 'main').